# Error code 140 in command running through Nextflow on SLURM

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

*[Note: question heavily edited to correspond to the actual problem]*

I'm trying to debug a command that fails only in specific conditions. The failure is with an exitcode 140, but I have no other information.

This command is `cat in_file | tr "\t" "\n" > out_file`, and it is part of a [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/) script, which is in turn run on a cluster with the [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/) scheduler.

As the command is `tr`, part of the GNU coreutils, I checked the [manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) and [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html), that only mention that "An exit status of zero indicates success, and a nonzero value indicates failure.", but this is not a standard error from [`errno.h` codes](http://mazack.org/unix/errno.php).

Comment: A process is allowed to exit with a code greater than 128, but this is discouraged and I don't think GNU `tr` does it. By convention the parent shell will assign more than 128 to `$?` if the process gets killed by a signal, so most likely this is what happens. The convention is err=128+sig, in this case 140=128+12. In several architectures (including x86 and ARM) the signal number 12 is SIGUSR2 (see `man 7 signal`) and the default action of SIGUSR2 is to terminate the process. What is the architecture?

Comment: This is with `x86_64`. It's on an Intel Xeon Gold, part of a computing cluster (hence the use of Nextflow for managing jobs)

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense now! It's an interaction: the cluster is run by SLURM, which sets a time limit on the jobs, and it can interrupt jobs with a specified [signal](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_signal). To ensure the jobs get killed nicely, Nextflow asks for a [SIGUSR2](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/2163) when time runs out. I will edit the question to make it more discoverable, thank you!

Comment: But what is the actual command? The error code is more likely coming from nextflow, or SLURM, not the command. Can you show us the relevant nextflow script? Are you sure ``in_file` exists and is in the directory you think it is? Do you have write access to the directory where `out_file` is and, if the file exists, to the file itself? Does removing the unnecessary pipe (`tr '\t' '\n' < in_file > out_file`) make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code you see won't be from `tr` but either from the nextflow or SLURM. A quick search suggests that it is indeed SLURM. See, for example, here:

> - A job/ process is not given enough memory or time: pipeline runs on large samples or datasets may require more memory or a higher time limit. When reported correctly, the pipeline will indicate an error status of 140 (for SGE or SLURM environments); however, memory issues can take many forms, and related error messages are not always clear. In this example case, the process PairedEndHisat failed due to insufficient memory, but indicated a general error status (1):

Or, [here](https://tracyxinwang.github.io/2018/11/13/slurm-exit-code/):

> 140  The job exceeded the “wall clock” time limit (as opposed to the CPU time limit).

I don't know much about this so I don't know who's right. However, this at least gives you the general direction: is the process taking a long time? Or, since you are trying to write to a file, do you have enough disk space to actually write?